I would like to know ydlidar.yaml's values (baudrate, etc.) to run ydlidar x3 pro
I tried to run ydlidar x3 pro on ros2 in ubuntu 20.04 LTS, but execution keeps stopping with error code: Error, cannot retrieve YDLidar health code: ffffffff. and i tried to look up the values ​​in ydlidar-SDK's datasheet, but x3 pro's params were not listed.
Does anyone know the params values ​​for running ydlidar x3 pro? please let me know
Current not working ydlidar.yaml code:
ydlidar_ros2_driver_node:
  ros__parameters:
    port: /dev/ttyUSB0
    frame_id: laser_frame
    ignore_array: ""
    baudrate: 230400
    lidar_type: 1
    device_type: 0
    sample_rate: 9
    intensity_bit: 0
    abnormal_check_count: 4
    fixed_resolution: true
    reversion: true
    inverted: true
    auto_reconnect: true
    isSingleChannel: false
    intensity: false
    support_motor_dtr: false
    angle_max: 180.0
    angle_min: -180.0
    range_max: 64.0
    range_min: 0.01
    frequency: 10.0
    invalid_range_is_inf: false

